# Android : Push data from android app to cloud space

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I was evaluating a homework assignment . I need to make an app that will eventually need to push data into a cloud . The data might be quite large actually . I checked out Google Android C2DM [here](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) .

But i realised that it is used to push small notifications from the cloud to the application . Can it be used to send fairly large data from the app to the cloud ? Or is there a suitable alternative that can be used ?

So my question is how to implement a way to send large data from your android app to a cloud .

Comment: I think what you need to do is create CMS(WebServer) to send large data.

Comment: @PAD can you provide some more details about it . ? i cant quite make out from what you say ... Do you mean a CMS as in a Content Management System ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [Java Client](http://sourceforge.net/p/zkboxjavaclient/wiki/zkBox%20Java%20Client%20-%20Save%20objects%20on%20the%20cloud/). You can save data on the cloud with it - @rockstar .